# eclipse not started from command line in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, java, eclipse

I installed latest version of Eclipse at /opt/ directory in my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. Then I created a soft link to open it through command line:

> sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse

When I tried to open the Eclipse from the command line via command:

**eclipse &**

an error message is poped up with message:

> **The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion
>   launcher jar.**

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually related to eclipse.ini file where you can configure the path.

Here is a another SO question with possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876538/the-eclipse-executable-launcher-was-unable-to-locate-its-companion-launcher-jar